# Customize screensaver in chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, screensaver

Is there a way to customize the Chromecast screensaver choosing your own images?

Alternatively can I write a receiver app that replaces the screensaver?

Comment: Wouldn't the recently added Backdrop feature solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The screensaver is actually a web page (https://clients3.google.com/cast/chromecast/home). You can redirect this to your own page using your router.

Comment: I can't do it with https: my page certificate will never match the certificate of google.com

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace or customize the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways

1. If you root it with Eureka, you get ssh access and everything
2. create a program that starts using chromecast always when its not in
   use

Comment: Seems that rooting requires an old buggy chromecast... solution 2. is good but I think I need an external polling client, right?